# In Jquery what is the difference between .prop and .attr?

Tags: jquery

I was reading the documentation for JQuery https://api.jquery.com/prop/ and I wasn't sure the difference between .prop and .attr?

They wrote this in there:

type property (or attribute)

```
$(elem).attr("checked") 
$(elem).prop("checked") 
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
```

Please point me to the right documentation or an example.

Comment: At least direct me to where the duplicate post is:

Comment: Found this for others: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr

Comment: Ya thats the dupe link i posted...